Have any philosophers used permutation/probability theory to justify our preference for simpler theories?
A dice roll landing on 6 has a probability of 1/6. Two dice rolls landing on 6 has a probability of 1/36. And so on.
The more components we add to an event, the longer and more specific that permutation becomes, and thus more unlikely. The total number of permutations also increases the more componenrs we add. Before, the permutations must be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. With two dice rolls, the permutations become {(1.2), (1,3), (1,4)…} and so on, which is obviously much larger.
Can the same be analogized for hypotheses? The more assumptions we add to a hypothesis, the greater the total number of permutations (perhaps possible worlds pertaining to different hypotheses), and the less likely that particular permutation of assumptions becomes.
Note: the SEP has a section that talks about the probabilistic/statistical justifications for simplicity, but that has more to do with models and curve fitting rather than more basic probability theory.

It's not 'permutation theory'- it's basic probability.

Please explain where in your example permutations enter into the game; thanks.

@ProfessorSushing true true, permutations are a part of probability, so it’s overall the same concept

@JoWehler I added an edit

Tall office buildings, airliners, cellphones, complex web sites... They all give me the willies! Yeah, but, I have to make a living and travel and stuff. Take a 'tablet' and write me in the morning. That's what I do.

Karl Popper discusses this in The Logic of Scientific Discovery. In a footnote on the chapter "Simplicity," he notes that Dorothy Wrinch and Harold Jeffreys suggested measuring the simplicity of a function by the "paucity of its freely adjustable parameters." See their paper, "On certain fundamental principles of scientific inquiry" in *Phil. Mag., Vol. 42, No. 249 (1921).
Harmann Weyl independently described this idea six years after Wrinch and Jeffreys (1927). He proposed that that when selecting what class of function one would choose to describe the data, one should prefer a "class of function" that has "mathematical simplicity."
All of Wrinch, Jeffreys, Weyl, and Popper rejected the idea that some prior probability of the theory is what makes it "simpler" or preferred. Rather, the simplicity was merely in the degrees of freedom: the "paucity" of parameters.
As expressed by Popper, the reason to prefer the simpler one is that it is more falsifiable: there are fewer parameters that could be adjusted in an ad-hoc manner to accomodate new observations.
Popper, in his postscript, Realism and the Aim of Science (1983), also describes the views of Leibniz:

[Leibniz] says that a hypothesis is the more 'probable' the greater its simplicity and power, and the greater the number of phenomena which it can 'solve' (explain) with the fewer (additional or ad hoc) 'assumptions'. ... There is no suggestion here that he realizes that simplicity, and explanatory power, are equivalent to logical improbability, in the sense of the probability calculus.


Trying to grok. "Leibniz, why did it have to be Leibniz..." Oh! Monads! I can get behind that.

A basic result in probability offers an obvious way to interpret O's wretched R. If you have n independent assumptions in your hypothesis, then the probability of them all being true is the product of their individual probabilities, so the more assumptions you add, the less likely your hypothesis becomes. Of course, what O's now horribly blunted and misused R neglects to consider, are the probabilities themselves. A hypothesis based on ten assumptions each with a high probability is a better bet than a hypothesis based on one wildly improbable assumption.

Agreed, which is why it’s best served as a tool for trimming hypotheses that seem to be a subset of another hypothesis that merely adds more assumptions. That way, you don’t have to know the probabilities!
